# Programa em c# que leia carateres e Substitua os caracteres

Tags: c#

Um Programa em c# que leias um alinha de caracteres,e imprima a mesma na consola de tal forma que as vogais sejam substituidas,pelo caracter que mais se repete na linha.

Comment: Ixe ai não vale hiem ... Você precisa fazer cara ... e trazer para gente as duvidas

Comment: Eu realmente não sei com proceder as regras da comunidade, mas eu sei que preciso muito de ajuda... @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi bem o que você deseja, mas seria algo assim ?

```
string line = "testandoyyiiaaaccccbbb";

    //Busca o caractere que mais se repete.
    var maxRepeat = line.ToArray()
                  .GroupBy(x => x.ToString())
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                                x => x.Count(), 
                                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                  .First();

    //Troca todas as vogais pelo caractere que mais se repete.
    var result = line.Replace("a", maxRepeat.Key)
                      .Replace("e", maxRepeat.Key)
                      .Replace("i", maxRepeat.Key)
                      .Replace("o", maxRepeat.Key)
                      .Replace("u", maxRepeat.Key);

    Console.WriteLine($"Caractere que mais se repete: {maxRepeat.Key}");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Quando você não entende, não responde. A pergunta é só um enunciado e realm ente não tem como ser respondida adequadamente. Eu tenho quase certeza que esse código não é o que a pessoa queria de fato, até porque dá para fazer algo muito melhor, e esse é o motivo porque não respondemos isso. Pode ser uma resposta, mas não é uma boa, ensina algo ruim para as pessoas.